# Converting an existing app using ButterKnife to an Android library

Tags: android, android-studio, refactoring, butterknife

I have this moderately massive application which I have to turn into an Android library. My application extensively depends on ButterKnife, and as per it's limitations I can't use ButterKnife anymore. An alternative to this is using ButterFork. My problem lies in the amount of refactoring I will have to do to change `R.id.resource` to `B.id.resource` 
Is there a shortcut or some work around for this problem? 
I am aware of the functionality of structural replace in Android Studio, but the thing is don't know how to write the script for replacing `R` with `B`

Comment: If you're on linux, you could do use `grep -rl 'old_val' ./ | xargs sed -i 's/old_val/new_val/g'` from the root of your java source, if the only change is that actual characters.  in your case: `grep -rl 'R.id.' ./ | xargs sed -i 's/R.id./B.id./g'`

Comment: did you find success in converting ? I converted but getting nullpointer exception for views ? can you suggest any solution ?

Comment: I converted but I had to go and do the changes manually everywhere